# Adding frontend global javascript in Magento 2 theme

Tags: magento2, javascript, theme, frontend

I am creating a new theme for Magento 2 to be used inhouse as a basetheme for new projects. I am basing it on "Zurb Foundation for sites" and this boilerplate includes js files what-input.js, jquery.js and foundation.js:

i have created foundation.js as such:

```
define([
'jquery',
'what-input'
],function($) {
    'use strict';
    $(function() {
        $(document).foundation();
    });
});
```

And what-input.js also has the same setup with define depending on jquery only. Am i doing this the right way? Will magento recognize what-input.js as a js module and load it when foundation.js is loaded? Also, how do i tell magento to load foundation.js?

These files are in theme_folder/web/js next to responsive.js and theme.js which both loads properly as far as i can tell.

EDIT:

Solved the issue i described in the comment by replacing the JS:

```
    "*": {
        "Mage2theme/js/foundation": {}
    }
```

With:

```
{
    "*": {
        "Mage2theme/js/foundation": {}
    }
}
```

But another problems arose, it does not copy the foundation.js file to pub/stacic theme folder so i get a 404 when trying to load it.

Comment: I have had some progress, i watched https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FJUJ5gZwT38 and read http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_init.html .So it seems using "<script type="text/x-magento-init">" is the correct way of adding these javascript but it generates the error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :" in the console and why it does that i do not know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So i solved it:

By changeing

```
{
    "*": {
        "Mage2theme/js/foundation": {}
    }
}
```

to

```
{
    "*": {
        "js/foundation": {}
    }
}
```

It started searching for it in the correct place and made the appropriate symlink in pub/static subfolder. It also seems i need to do the same thing with what-input.js.

Not sure if i am missing something here because i saw some references pointing at `require([])` at http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js-resources.html but this will have to do for now anyway.

Some things to note:

For adding the  tags i used default.xml layout and inserted a phtml template in the content as such:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
            <referenceContainer name="content">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="mage2themejs" as="mage2themejs" template="Magento_Theme::js/main.phtml"/>
            </referenceContainer>
        </body>
</page>
```

main.phtml then looks like this:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "js/foundation": {}
        }
    }
</script>
```

And my foundation-init.js after being renamed since i also needed to include actual foundation.js finally looks like this:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'js/foundation'
    'js/what-input'
],function($) {
    'use strict';
    $(function() {
        $(document).foundation();
    });
});
```

By adding js/ it properly includes the specified file from themes web/js/ directory. I hope this information will be helpful.